# Bootstrap Collapse with aria-expanded="true" doesn't work as expected

Tags: bootstrap-4

I use this following code to create collapse-element with Bootstrap 4.5:

```
    <div class="container py-2">
        <div class="row">
<button class="btn btn-success my-3" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseSelectTable" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseSelectTable">toggle element</button>
            <div class="container collapse" id="collapseSelectTable">
            <div class="row bg-light border border-info rounded align-items-center">
                <p>the table</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Clicking on the button toggles the collapsed element just fine, but I expect that it should be visible 'cos "aria-expanded=true" as explained in  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/collapse/#accessibility .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `show` class is needed on the `collapse` element to make it open by default...

> "If you’ve set the collapsible element to be open by default using the
> show class, set aria-expanded="true" on the control instead."

https://codeply.com/p/wZCrMNXG1S

Comment: If I understand it all well, aria-expanded doesn't contribute to the state of the element? The default state of the collapsible element is controlled by adding or removing 'show' in it's class. 
What is the purpose of "aria-expanded" attribute?

Comment: As stated in the docs, "This attribute explicitly conveys the current state of the collapsible element tied to the control to screen readers and similar assistive technologies." It's not going to control the browser state, only convey it to accessibility devices.